# python pandas - reduce consecutive dupes in one column, while maintaining sequential order in another

Tags: python, pandas, sorting, dataframe, shuffle

I have a dataframe like:

```
a  |  b  |  c
a     1     2
b     1     3
c     1     1
d     2     2
e     2     3
f     2     1
```

I would like to shuffle the rows to reduce consecutive dupes in `B` while putting them in sequential order in `C` as much as possible. The dataframe may have hundreds of rows.

The desired output for the dataframe above might look like:

```
a  |  b  |  c
c     1     1
f     2     1
a     1     2
d     2     2
b     1     3
e     2     3
```

There are no consecutive duplicates in column `B`, and `C` is in sequence as much as possible based on the rows in the dataframe. `C` can take on values from 1 to 5, while `B` can have alot of different values.

Where the criteria can no longer be met and there are still rows in the dataframe, it's ok to put the row(s) anywhere in the dataframe(if that is easier).

so far, I was shown a way to ensure that consecutive values do not occur in `B`:

```
np.random.seed(0)
(df.groupby(df.groupby('B').cumcount(), group_keys=False)
   .apply(lambda x: x.sample(frac=1))
   .reset_index(drop=True))
```

But I am having difficulty getting it to incorporate the sequencing of column `C` into the code.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: The output of the method you were shown depends on the random seed; in your case, it just happens to avoid consecutive values in column `b`, but that will change if you re-run with a different seed value.

Comment: @cs95 cool, I hadn't seen that question or your answer! Yes, this is an interesting problem, but not so simple. I guess the ideal answer would be an "unsort" algorithm that finds a maximum-entropy configuration of `b` values within each `c` group.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Sorting by `c` and then `b` is enough for your example DataFrame, but it will start to break down once `b` takes on duplicate values for a given `c` value:

```
df.sort_values(by=['c', 'b'])
   a  b  c
2  c  1  1
5  f  2  1
0  a  1  2
3  d  2  2
1  b  1  3
4  e  2  3
```

Comment: @WeNYoBen, this solution is not the most general approach, but it exactly reproduces the expected output provided in the question.